# Unable to understand _IO_puts

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I am a computer science 1st year student and we have C programming language as one of our subjects. Since, this is my first time dealing with any programming language at all, please pardon my absolute little understanding of the basics.

So, I was trying to understand a simple **Hello World** program and specifically how it works internally. The program is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

And although there are plenty of online resources that I found via Google around this topic, for example:

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/448766/gdb-debugger-problem and http://osteras.info/personal/2013/10/11/hello-world-analysis.html etc.

these are pretty overwhelming and I am still trying to understand it one by one. At the moment I am stuck with the part (in most of the resources that I referred) that says that

> printf

function, basically internally calls

> _IO_puts

Now how does it reach all the way there, is something that I am still trying to understand and that's not my concenrn in this quesiton.

My concern is, when I looked up the *_IO_puts* fucntion, it shows something like this:

```
int _IO_puts (const char *str)
```

taken from here :
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/ioputs.c.html

So my assumption is that all that needs to be passed to the above function is a string. But, when I look at the GDB code, I see that it shows something like this:

```
_IO_puts (str=0x555555554d60 "Hello World!")
```

Now my question is, what is **str=0x555555554d60** in the above?

Comment: `0x555555554d60` is the (virtual) memory address where the the "Hello World!" string is stored. But there's something important you should know: `printf` usually does __not__ call `__IO_puts`: it's your _compiler_ which optimizes the `printf("...\n")` into a `puts("...")`. Also, the `main` function should return an `int`, not `void`, even if there's no need of a `return` statement in c99.

Comment: If you don't believe that, compile your program into assembly with `cc -Wall -S -O2 main.c` and check the `main.s` output. (the `-O2` is to let `gcc` generate more lisible / less boilerplate assembly; that optimization will happen even without `-O2`).

Comment: @AndyDalton please do not correct questions: if they were correct, there would be no point in asking them in the 1st place ;-)

Comment: @mosvy the correction was totally unrelated to the question, but point taken.

Comment: @mosvy Better use the `-Os` optimization level when compiling to readable assembler code. This optimization level gives you the shortest assembler code that your compiler is able to produce. With `-O2` you run the risk that the compiler does clever tricks like loop unrolling which inflate the resulting assembler code to insane sizes. `-Os` is really the perfect optimization level for quickly understanding what the compiled code does.

Comment: @cmaster Your point is moot since that program contains no loop to unroll, and that `printf` -> `puts` optimization also happens without any `-O` flag. But according to the `gcc` manual `-O2` is not enough to let it unroll loops: `-O3` is needed for that.

Comment: @mosvy It's not just the loop unrolling. It's also other optimizations that tend to blow up the code. I've used both `-S -Os` and `-S -O2` enough to know that `-S -O2` is generally not a good idea. Independent of this example. And I tried to share this experience. Because if you don't know that `-Os` exists (like many people do), and don't know that it might be a really good idea to use when using `-S`, you are bound to have a much harder time to understand what your compiler tries to tell you. For me, it's become a reflex: When I add `-S` I also, immediately change the optimization to `-Os`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, what is str=0x555555554d60 in the above?

The C language passes strings around by passing the address of the first character of the string. The end of the string is marked by a zero byte in memory. Presumably, 0x555555554d60 is the address of the first character of "Hello World!\0" in virtual memory at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

`str=0x555555554d60 "Hello World!"` is just the way that `gdb` prints this one argument. It does try to include any information in its printout that you *may* find helpful. **This printout is *inspired* by the C syntax of the original code, but it's by far not correct C code.**

- `str=` The argument has no name in the compiled code. But `gdb` can infer the name of the variable in the original C code. Since names are typically given to variables to make their meaning easier to understand, `gdb` tells you that this particular variable is called `str`.
- `=0x555555554d60` The variable in question is a pointer, and as such it contains a memory address. `gdb` tells you that this is the address that was passed to the function.
- `"Hello World!"` Because the argument is a `char*`, and `char*` is usually used to pass around strings, `gdb` helpfully adds the information that the bytes `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', 0` are stored behind the passed address. I.e. the `'H'` is stored exactly at the address `0x555555554d60`, the `'e'` is found one byte further at `0x555555554d61`, and so on, until the compiler finds the terminating `0` byte at address `0x555555554d6c`.

It prints this information so that you can see at a glance: "Ah, yes, it's passing the address `0x555555554d60` to the function as an argument called `str`, which happens to be the address of the string `"Hello World!"` in memory.